# Casting int64_t * to uint64_t *

Tags: c++

The signed integer pointer is the output of `some_vector.data()` of a `std::vector<int64_t> some_vector`, but I know all the values are positive and I want to cast that integer to an unsigned integer. How can I do that and "reinterpret" the vector values as unsigned?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this? What's wrong with just using them as `int64_t`s whose values all happen to be positive?

Comment: Note that, prior to C++20, a positive signed integer and the same value as an unsigned integer might have different bit representations. It was only in C++20 that the standard settled on two's complement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply cast the pointer to the desired type and I think this will almost always work:

```
uint64_t * data = (uint64_t *)some_vector.data();
```

However I am not sure if this is allowed or safe according to the C++ standard.  (Search for "strict aliasing" to learn about one type of pitfall.)  And someone will probably tell you there is a better type of cast you can use.

It would be much safer to just leave the type of the pointer as it is, and then when you have an actual `int64_t` value you can implicitly convert it to a `uint64_t` or cast it.

```
int64_t * data = ...;
uint64_t x = data[1];
```

Comment: The strict-aliasing rules do allow this: *"Given an object with effective type T1, using an lvalue expression (typically, dereferencing a pointer) of a different type T2 is undefined behavior, unless: <...> - T2 is a signed or unsigned version of a type that is compatible with T1."*  It's still likely better to avoid the situation though.

Comment: @MilesBudnek That's the C rule. The C++ rule (with the same result in this case) is in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr#basic.lval-11.2: "_If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar to one of the following types the behavior is undefined: [...] a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object_"

Comment: @user17732522 Sure, my quote was from cppreference, not directly from the standard.  They say the same thing in different words though.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the values when you access them, there is no need to cast the whole vector.